# How to set the project root directory as the destination directory for a custom Maven Mojo plugin?

Tags: maven

I have writen a custom Mojo plugin to extract a zip file to a directory in the a project. 
This is my destination directory in the mojo class.

```
String destinationDirectory = "lib";
```

It is properly working and create a directory and extract the content of the zip to the file.

Now what I want is extract that content into the project's root directory.

If I give it like following it gives an error since destination directory is empty.

```
String destinationDirectory = "";
```

How can I get this done?

Following are the method that I created to extract the zip.

```
public void unpack(String zipFilePath, String destDirectory) throws IOException {



        File destDir = new File(destDirectory);

        //make the units directory if it is not exists.
        if (!destDir.exists()) {
            destDir.mkdir();
        }
        ZipInputStream zipIn = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(zipFilePath));
        ZipEntry entry = zipIn.getNextEntry();

        // iterates over entries in the zip file
        while (entry != null) {
            String filePath = destDirectory + File.separator + entry.getName();
            if (!entry.isDirectory()) {
                // if the entry is a file, extracts it
                extractFile(zipIn, filePath);
            } else {
                // if the entry is a directory, make the directory
                File dir = new File(filePath);
                dir.mkdir();
            }
            zipIn.closeEntry();
            entry = zipIn.getNextEntry();
        }
        zipIn.close();
    }
    /**
     * Extracts a zip entry
     * @param zipIn  zip entry found in the main zip file
     * @param filePath destination directory of the zip entry
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private void extractFile(ZipInputStream zipIn, String filePath) throws IOException {
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filePath));
        byte[] bytesIn = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
        int read = 0;
        while ((read = zipIn.read(bytesIn)) != -1) {
            bos.write(bytesIn, 0, read);
        }
        bos.close();
    }
```

How can I get the existing project's root directory in the run-time when the Mojo is executing ?

Comment: You know that maven-assmbly-plugin and maven-dependency-plugin exist which can extract archives very well, so i don't see the intention of your plugin?

Comment: The situation here is I have an archetype of a project. It has the packaging type "maven-archetype". If I am using maven-dependency plugin to extract the zip file packaging should be maven-plugin. I cannot achieve both at once so that I am using this custom Mojo to get this task done.

Comment: So why not using maven-archetype-plugin ? Can you elaborate a little bit more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding the dependency-plugin to the pom.xml in the `src/main/resources/archetype-resources`directory.

Since the maven-dependency-plugin is a plugin and cannot include in the archetype and on the other hand, the project which get created from the archetype is the one that should include the capability of extracting the zip file to the project I included the dependency plugin as follows in the project pom as follows which is the correct place to include the plugin.

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>truezip-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-package</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <verbose>true</verbose>
                            <fileset>
                                <!--This directory is to be modified-->
                                <directory>${path-to-the-zip-file}
                                </directory>
                                <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}</outputDirectory>
                            </fileset>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```